# Не распознанные символы Java

Tags: java

Добрый день.
Есть файл с расширением .class.
Декомпилировал его с помощью Fernflower.
Но часть символов почему-то не отображается (пример ниже). Можно ли это как-то исправить?

```
 public void CallSave() {
      this.record.setCallResult(CallResult.ANSWER);
      this.UpdateFields("�����");
      this.CallFinish();
```

Comment: в байте коде можно посмотреть константы, они будут записаны в виде юникода LDC "\u043f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442" (для System.out.println("привет ");)

Comment: Не совсем понял, как именно и где это нужно сделать:(

Comment: например в идеи View -> Show ByteCode, встроенный декомпилятор тоже без проблем видит юникод

Comment: >>Не совсем понял, как именно и где это нужно сделать<< в настройках вашего декомпилятора. В этом декомпилированном исходнике - данные потеряны, в них вы больше не найдёте исходную строку. Возвращайтесь к стадии декомпиляции и попытайтесь добиться от декомпилятора работы в UTF8 строках

Comment: Дело в том, что декомплировал исходник онлайн. Теперь, на сколько понимаю, придется какой-то установить. Что можете порекомендовать?